# Days Between Dates by Grouping (R)

Tags: r

I have a data set look like this:

```
ID | SKU | PurchaseDate
84 | TRP | 42027
84 | LTH | 42027
84 | IB229US | 42027
84 | IB229US | 42104
```

To load the above snippet as a data frame, the code is:

```
id<-c(84,84,84,84,84,84)
date<-c(42027, 42027, 42027, 42104, 42123, 42167)
SKU<- c("TRP", "LTH", "IB229US", "IB229US", "BTH", "IB229US")
data<-data.frame(id,date,SKU)
```

I'm trying to figure out average days between repurchase of the same SKU.
Right now i'm able to find days between repurchase in general but not by SKU using:

```
data$dayssincelastpurchase<-unlist(by(data$date,data$ID,
                   function(x) c(NA,diff(x))))
```

How could i go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: If you have the time to get familiar with a new package, do take a look at the `summarize()` function (and the `group_by()` function) within the `dplyr` package, especially at the examples in the corresponding help section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` solution. First you arrange by date, then group by SKU and finally add the days since last SKU purchase.

```
library(dplyr)    
data <- data %>%
    arrange(date) %>%
    group_by(SKU) %>%
    mutate(dayssincelastpurchase=date - lag(date))
```